# A simple windows Batch file to run java

Tags: java, batch-file

m new to java. I want to run java from windows batch file. I have a compiled class- Main.class in a directory. I want to run this with a batch file put in the same directory.
I have a system variable set to `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin`

And what if I want to compile the class with batch file first ?

Comment: You can use %JAVA_HOME%\java Main

Comment: One small thing, the JAVA_HOME should not include \bin since the HOME is really `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06`. To use it, you do "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" Main

Answer (score 3):

Execution:

```
@echo off
"%JAVA_HOME%\java.exe" Main
PAUSE
```

Compiling would be replacing the line with

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\javac" Main.java
```

**Optional Stuff:**

`echo off` turns off echo of the commands to cmd

`pause` is so that the cmd window doesn't close immediately at the end of execution(so you can read the output of your command)

Comment: From the main method of Main.java I created a new file called- MyNew.jave, When I wanna compile it says- cant find symbol - MyNew newclass=new MyNew();

Comment: `MyGen gen = new MyGen();` You need to add an import to member containing the MyGen class. Are you doing that? Look into ant, if you are building an entire project.

Answer (score 0):

Compile Your Code Using:

```
javac Main.java
```

Run Your Code Using:

```
java Main =>starts your code
```

To Get More Info About The javac tool(output name,disable warnings, etc...) [Press Here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html).

Comment: it shows no classDefinitionFound error but the class file-Main.class is there .

Comment: Read this to get some idea about this error : http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Answer (score 0):

```
javac cfm jar Main.jar Main.class manifest.txt
```

Make a manifest.txt containing:

```
Main-Class: Main
```

followed by a newline character to work properly (hit Enter once).
And make a batch file in the same folder of output containing:

```
@echo off
 set jarpath="Main.jar"
 java -jar %jarpath% %CD%Config.txt
 PAUSE
```

Run the batch! :)